# A mistake in Munkres' Topology

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres' Topology, there is a lemma;

> **Lemma 23.2.** If the sets $C$ and $D$ form a separation of $X$, and if $Y$ is connected subspace of $X$, then $Y$ lies within either $C$ or $D$.

The proof is correct. But the issue is that this lemma is valid if $X$ is not connected. Because if pair $C$, $D$ is a separation, then $X$ is not connected. Thus, we cannot use this lemma if the space is connected.But, he uses the lemma the rest of the chapter.

Isn't it right?

Comment: seems perfectly okay to me. If the space is connected then separations do not exist and so it holds true trivially.

Comment: It would be good to give an example of where you think the lemma is applied improperly. (As person says, there is no issue with the lemma itself… it’s correct as stated.)

Comment: You might want to learn about [vacuous truth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth#:~:text=In%20mathematics%20and%20logic%2C%20a,does%20not%20really%20say%20anything.).

Answer (score 3):

As you say, the lemma is correct. I can only find a single use of it in the proof of Theorem 23.4 which is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: The proof of Theorem 23.3., he uses this lemma. For us to use this lemma, space must be disconnected.

Comment: @endvc1 It is also a proof by contradiction which *assumes the existence of a separation*.

Comment: He assumes that $Y$ is not connected, i say that the $X$ must be disconnected

Comment: @endvc1 $X$ is irrelevant here. Munkres considers $Y = \bigcup A_\alpha$ and assumes that $Y$ has a separation.

Comment: thank you, I understand now